# Phonegap Build play local audio

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I would like to play a song with phonegape build. My problem is that in an phonegap build project, all files are in the same folder. So that i dont now what the correct path is to my soundfile, included in the project. It worked good with an url like shown in your examples. I tried diffrent paths to access the audio file for example :

```
"/android_asset/www/test.mp3" 
"/asset/test.mp3" 
"test.mp3"
```

I have no clue why it wont worked, here i show my problem on fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/b7BPV/ 
Thanks for help and greetings from germany!!! Your awesome!!

Comment: did you try "/test.mp3" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the location of test.mp3 if you have the file located in your www folder

```
src="test.mp3"
```

the change you require for your code is

```
<a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="playAudio('test.mp3');">Play Audio</a>
```

Comment: Where do i have to insert the src="test.mp3" in the onclick?

Comment: try this onclick="playAudio('test.mp3');"

Comment: and change the New Media(url, ...  to New Media(src,...    correct?

Comment: i changed my answer for the specific answer